# SQlite - OFFSET clause not working! (java)

Tags: java, sqlite, offset

I use `SQlite` as a database in my java application, and I want to load last 10 tuple which i insert in database,
I do it as below code :

```
int startP = (numPrev()-10>0) ? numPrev() - 10 : 0;
PreparedStatement s;
s = db.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ? ORDER BY Date LIMIT 11 OFFSET ? ");
s.setInt(1, id);
s.setInt(2,startP);
ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery();
```

but it load first 10 tuple, and don't mention to `OFFSET`!

Comment: Oh, wow! Using placeholder for OFFSET where it might not even work, but concatenating ID

Comment: What means "not working"? Do you get an exception or wron result?

Comment: @Jens It returns first 10 tuple not from the offset that i set!

Comment: @user3933607 and which value has `startP`?

Comment: @Jens numPrev() method returns num row in table, so startP is row-10 or 0

Comment: @Konstantin V. Salikhov, I update my query, now I use placeholder for both :)

Comment: @user3933607 Can you try it with a fix value so you can see if you query is the problem?

Comment: @Jens, I think I have found the problem: 
I store date in [text format](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_data_types.htm) and order result by date parameter which is not work properly ! 

So how should I store date ?